# vk.api messages.getHistory Не работает с беседами

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Если, при использовании метода `messages.getHistory` передавать `user_id`, то всё прекрасно работает.
При передачи `chat_id` выдаёться ошибка `vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied`.

У бота есть все права (через токен). Метод `messages.send` прекрасно работает. Использую метод, так:
`print(vk.messages.getHistory(group_id=187886390, peer_id=2000000001, count = 1))`

Comment: (недоступно для вызовов от имени сообщества)
Используйте токен от своего аккаунта для вызова параметра getHistory из беседы.

Comment: @ДанилкинPUBG , если передовать user_id, то метод работает. В документации сказано, что данный метод можно вызвать с ключом сообщества.